# i can not user ip addr to connect ldap server

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

i want use java and ldaps to connect ldapService. but its wrong.
the problem is :
       nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: 192.168.174.145:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present]

if i use hostname:636 it is success . i do not know why .can you help me ? very thanks

```
public class SslLdapContextSource extends LdapContextSource {
    @Override
    protected Hashtable<String, Object> getAnonymousEnv() {
        Hashtable<String, Object> anonymousEnv = super.getAnonymousEnv();
        anonymousEnv.put("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
        anonymousEnv.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", CustomSSLSocketFactory.class.getName());
        anonymousEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        return anonymousEnv;
    }
}



public class CustomSslSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;

    public CustomSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new DummyTrustmanager()}, new SecureRandom());
            socketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
        return new CustomSslSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return socketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return socketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, Senter code heretring string, int num, boolean bool) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(socket, string, num, bool);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String string, int num) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(string, num);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String string, int num, InetAddress netAdd, int i) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(string, num, netAdd, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress netAdd, int num) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(netAdd, num);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress netAdd1, int num, InetAddress netAdd2, int i) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(netAdd1, num, netAdd2, i);
    }



    public static class DummyTrustmanager implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String string) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String string) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
        }

    }
}

 @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSourceTarget());
    }
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSourceTarget() {
        if(!useSSL){
            String urls = "ldap://"+url+":"+port;
            LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
            ldapContextSource.setUrl(urls);
            //ldapContextSource.setBase(base);
            ldapContextSource.setUserDn(username);
            ldapContextSource.setPassword(password);
            ldapContextSource.setReferral(referral);
            ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
            return ldapContextSource;
        }else{
            String urls = "ldaps://"+url+":"+port;
            SslLdapContextSource contextSource = new SslLdapContextSource();
            contextSource.setUrl(urls);
            contextSource.setUserDn(username);
            contextSource.setPassword(password);
            contextSource.setPooled(false);
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
            return contextSource;
        }
    }
```

i want use ldaps://192.168.174.145:636 to connect ldapService.but now i only can use ldaps://test:636 to connect ldapService.
192.168.174.145 and test is same computer

Comment: Unless the IP address is in the certificate as a subject alternative name you can't do this.

Answer (score -1):

When an SSL/TLS connection is established various checks are performed as part of the server authentication.
I.e.

- Is the server certificate valid?
- Is the server certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority?
- Does the certificate belong to the server the client is connecting too?

For the last check either the Subject CN of the Subject DN of the server cert or values of the Subject Alternative Name (IP / DNS) extension of the server cert are checked. Please also see [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)

Comment: (3) is accomplished via a digital signature. Hostname checking is yet another phase.